# Mustache: referring to elements in nested list iterations

Tags: python, iteration, mustache

I was wondering whether there is a way to explicitly refer to elements in a nested list iteration in Pystache. More specifically, I have two lists:

```
xs = [x1,x2]
ys = [y1,y2,y3]
```

When iterating over one of those lists, I can simply use the implicit iterator `{{.}}`. But when I want to nest iterations over these two lists, I need a way to refer to the current element of `xs` and `ys`. For example, I want to get every combination of x's and y's, with an imaginary template like the following:

```
{{#xs}}
{{#ys}}
blah <{{x}}> <{{y}}> .
{{/ys}}
{{/xs}}
```

Which should yield:

```
blah <x1> <y1> .
blah <x1> <y2> .
blah <x1> <y3> .
blah <x2> <y1> .
blah <x2> <y2> .
blah <x2> <y3> .
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the Mustache template? The PHP implementation seems to have a pragma `{{%IMPLICIT-ITERATOR iterator=i}}`, which would be very cool here, but there is no such thing in Pystache, right?

(And since it is only the template that specifies which lists need to be combined, I'd like to not build the Cartesian product of the lists beforehand but would prefer a way to do this in the template.)

Comment: Would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544391/mustache-or-handlebars-iterating-over-two-lists

Comment: Yes, rearranging the data, so I'm only iterating over one thing, works; that's what I ended up doing. Still, I was wondering whether there is a way to do this without rearranging the data (which is not always an elegant option).

Comment: A more mustachey answer than preprocessing would be to use a View Model to present the data. In your case, you could probably get by with a list comprehension or simple generator.